# Selenium no logra encontrar mi elemento para realizar clic

Tags: python, selenium

Estoy haciendo web scraping con selenium, pero este no logra encontrar mi elemento para darle click el XPATH  que estoy colocando debería poder hacer que yo realice el click.

```
/html/body/span[5]/a
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo llamo desde selenium con la siguiente linea:

```
security_boton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/span[5]/a')
security_boton.click()
```

Comment: en 2 días podrás aceptar tu propia respuesta y así se considerará *solucionado* tu problema. SI quieres cerrar tu pregunta, la puedes reportar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré el problema, Selenium no lograba encontrar el XPATH ya que esta pagina eran varias paginas HTML dentro de una sola, la solución fue simple al menos en mi caso debía iniciar sesión ya que primero se tenia que iniciar sesión con la pagina luego de esto mande la petición de redireccionamiento con driver.get('la dirección del formulario aparte')

Comment: algún ejemplo que aportar?